# Android - Get the subtraction to the next block

Tags: android

I need to know how to get the subtraction to the next block, the blocks are `60` each time:

```
60 is the first block
120 is the next block // 60 + 60
180 is the next block // 120 + 60
240 is the next block // 180 + 60
and so on...
```

The number could be anything (with or without decimals, but if has decimals, it will have 2, like: 123.45)

For example, if the `Number` is `123` what I need to get is the subtraction to the next block:

```
Number = 123; // is between the second (120) and the third (180)
NumberFinal = 180 - Number = 57;
Number = 17.56; // is before the first (60)
NumberFinal = 60 - Number = 42.44;
```

The thing is that the blocks have no limit, could be for example `9540`, so it is really hard to do it by hand every `60`.

Is there any way to make a loop or something to get what I need? I use Android Studio, I never used loops, and I'm not sure if that will work and help me to get what I need.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using the modulus operator.

```
public double getNextBlock(double number) {
    return 60.0 - (number % 60);
}
```

Calling this method results in the following:

```
getNextBlock(123);    // 57.0
getNextBlock(17.56);  // 42.44
getNextBlock(9500);   // 40.0
```

Comment: Realized much easier to just use modulus so I updated the answer.